# Google analytics code adds a 'snapnames request' to my website?

Tags: optimization, google-analytics, pagespeed

I am creating a subdomain website like this: testing.test.com

When I add the google analytics tracking code to my website and run a page speed test I see that it is looking up whether "testing.com" is available (my subdomain name + .com) on snapnames.com.

This isn't so much of a problem except my site loads in only 400ms and this requests takes 1,36 seconds. Do you guys know any way to get rid of the snapnames request?

Comment: I don't think that's google analytics.

Comment: That's what i thought too at first. But if i delete my GA code it disappears.

Comment: I'm with @Eduardo here, that isn't even remotely GA behavior. Can you post your GA code?

Comment: Check your browser console to see the requests going out, as i'm not aware of any GA code that would behave in this way. Do you have other 3rd party tracking code installed that could be doing this?